# Can't find the frequency of the signal using Fourier transform

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, signal-processing, fft

I integrate a system of 400 differential equations using `odeint` (the first 200 equations are the equation of x component of 200 neurons, and the other 200 of y component). So the main body of my code that does the integration is this

```py
t_final = 100.0
dt = 0.01
t = np.arange(0, t_final, dt)
sol = odeint(full_derivative, z0, t)
x10 = sol[:,9]
y10 = sol[:,209]
```

It doesn't matter which is the model that I use (I don't want to make things more complicated), but the integration part is correct. In `x10` there is the signal of x-component for the 10th oscillator of my system, which looks like that

[image]

It is obvious that this is a periodic signal with a specific period and frequency. So I want to do a Fourier transform to find this frequency. I use this code to do the transform

```py
from scipy import fftpack

f_s = len(t)//2

X = fftpack.fft(x10)
freqs = fftpack.fftfreq(len(x10)) * f_s

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.stem(freqs, np.abs(X))
ax.set_xlabel('Frequency in Hertz [Hz]')
ax.set_ylabel('Frequency Domain (Spectrum) Magnitude')
ax.set_xlim(-f_s / 2, f_s / 2)
#ax.set_ylim(-5, 110)
```

and the result that I take is this (which is not very beautiful because it shows that the frequency is approximately zero).

[image]

What can I do to fix the bug in my code?

**p.s.** *Maybe in this example it is relatively obvious which is the frequency of the system, but if I change the parameters of my problem I can end up in more complicated solutions. This is the reason why I want to do a fourier transform.*

Comment: until you get solid results I suggest you use a sine curve as your input signal ... that gives you a known input frequency with a predictable output ... tighten up your code with a sine curve until your output is showing a matching frequency as your input then worry about complex input signals

Answer (score 0):

The plot makes sense to me if the time unit in the first plot is second, because then you should have an important frequency component close to 0.1Hz.

I see in the first part you are using `dt = 0.01` and I understand this is the sampling interval. In second you are using `f_s = len(t) // 2` that should be the one `1.0/dt` this will actually make the frequency you will find even smaller since now `f_s` will be 100 instead of 5000, but the frequency you are searching is still ~0.2% of the sampling frequency, so you have will have to zoom in to the region of interest. Other thing to pay attention is that if the signal has non-zero mean there will be a peak corresponding to frequency zero.